# How to find a word in a cell and delete the rows above in openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to delete the first rows until the table heading appears, or a word, in this case "Account"

```
wb2=openpyxl.load_workbook(Feb,data_only='True')
ws2=wb2.active

mr2=ws2.max_row
mc2=ws2.max_column



for items in sorted(ws2.merged_cells.ranges):
    ws2.unmerge_cells(str(items) )
for row in ws2.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        for j in range(1,mc2+1):
            for i in range(1,mr2+1):
                if ws2.cell(row=i,column=j).value=="Account":
                    firstrow=int(cell.row)
                    ws2.delete_rows(1, firstrow-1)
```

It also deletes the row with the heading, even though I've put firstrow-1

I have tried also like this:

```
for row in ws2.rows:
     for cell in row:
         if cell.value == "Account":
             firstrow=int(cell.row)
             ws2.delete_rows(1,cell.row-1)
```

but the second time it deletes all the table.

If you have any other idea to delete the first rows until "Account" appears, even in pandas, please help.

Thanks

Comment: Break out of the loop before you delete anything because you're changing the indices that the loop is based on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by CharlieClark, you do need to exit once you find the first occurrence of "Account" word. I removed some redundant code, but have tried to keep as much of your code as is. This code will iterate through each column and each cell row till it finds the first occurrence of 'Account' word. It will then proceed to delete all rows above that row and break out of the loops. Note there are two loops, so the second one also should be broken out of...

In the example below, note that there are two cells with Account, but as the column is in the outer loop, it will find the one in 5th column, remove everything above. I hope that is what you are looking for. Else, you will need to interchange the row and column for loops...

```
wb2=openpyxl.load_workbook(Feb,data_only='True')
ws2=wb2.active
mr2=ws2.max_row
mc2=ws2.max_column
for items in sorted(ws2.merged_cells.ranges):
    ws2.unmerge_cells(str(items) )

for j in range(1,mc2+1):
        for i in range(1,mr2+1):
            if ws2.cell(row=i,column=j).value=="Account":
                if i > 1:
                    ws2.delete_rows(1, i-1)
                break  ## Exit inner for loop
        else: ## Will run unless above for loop encounter breaks. Used to exit both FOR loops
            continue
        break

wb2.save('Output.xlsx')
```

**Input file**

[image]

**Output post deletion**

[image]

Comment: Using your code, i managed to delete the rows above, if necessary. But for some cases, for some files, the Account is on the first row, and it deletes the entire table. I don't know if Account is always on the first row

Comment: You are right, `delete_row()` will delete all rows if Account is in the first row. What should happen in that case? No rows to be deleted?

Comment: Yes, in that case no rows should be deleted

Comment: Added that additional check. Ideally `delete_rows()` should delete 0 rows, but could be a bug. Either way, added an IF loop that will skip the delete and break out of the loop in case Account is found in first line. Answer above updated. See if this resolves your question