# Deleting all rows above a value found in column A of an Excel sheet with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am new to Python and coding and decided to just start a project to learn. The code copies and pastes the original file into a new workbook (original is protected by the author) what I would like to happen next is every row above "Location : 001 General Notes" be deleted. I am not getting any errors when running the script, but nothing is being deleted. The code I am using to delete the rows is one I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73527572/how-to-find-a-word-in-a-cell-and-delete-the-rows-above-in-openpyxl#:%7E:text=This%20code%20will%20iterate%20through%20each%20column%20and,that%20row%20and%20break%20out%20of%20the%20loops.).

```
import openpyxl as xl
#Creates new workbook, saves it over the original, removes design
path1 = "/home/user/Delavue/84-22-1037 Piedmont Model Takeoff.xlsx"

wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename=path1)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]

wb2 = xl.Workbook()
ws2 = wb2.create_sheet(ws1.title)

for row in ws1:
    for cell in row:
        ws2[cell.coordinate].value=cell.value
del wb2['Sheet']
#Find location 001 and delete everything above it
mr1=ws2.max_row
mc1=ws2.max_column
for j in range(1,mr1+1):
    for i in range(1,mc1+1):
        if ws2.cell(row=i,column=j).value=="Location : 001 General Notes":
            if i > 1:
                ws2.delete_rows(1, i-1)
            break
wb2.save(path1)
```

Here is a snippet of what the file looks:

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjPMV.png)

I am now trying to delete all of the rows above the "first location". This first location always starts with "Location : " but is followed by different things every time so I will not be able to use ==

I typed up the following, it runs without any errors but it does not do anything. I only need it to delete the first location and then stop.

Picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kA8Gj.png

```
#Creates new workbook, saves it over the original, removes design
path1 = "/home/sean-desmet/Delavue/84-22-1037 Piedmont Model Takeoff.xlsx"

wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename=path1)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]

wb2 = xl.Workbook()
ws2 = wb2.create_sheet(ws1.title)

for row in ws1:
    for cell in row:
        ws2[cell.coordinate].value=cell.value
del wb2['Sheet']

#Find location 001 and delete everything above it

mr1=ws2.max_row
mc1=ws2.max_column
for j in range(1,mc1+1):
    for i in range(1,mr1+1):
        if ws2.cell(row=i,column=j).value=="Location : 001 General Notes":
            if i > 1:
                ws2.delete_rows(1, i)
            break
        else:
            continue
        break
#Go to correct location and delete rows above it
mr2=ws2.max_row
mc2=ws2.max_column
for n in range(1,mc2+1):
    for m in range(1,mr2+1):
        if cell.value is not None:
            if type(cell.value) != int:
                if 'Location : ' in ws2.cell(row=m,column=n).value:
                    if m > 1:
                        ws2.delete_rows(1, m)
                    break
                else:
                    continue
                break
wb2.save(path1)`
```

Comment: I figured it out, mc and mr needed to be swapped here: for j in range(1,mr1+1):
    for i in range(1,mc1+1):

Comment: You understand that if you open an xlsx file, modify it then save it with whatever name you like (or even the same name in a different location) the original xlsx file is not changed in any way and the xlsx you saved has all the data from the original xlsx other than what data you removed/changed during modification?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this: "the original xlsx file is not changed in any way and the xlsx you saved has all the data from the original xlsx other than what data you removed/changed during modification?"

And why it is is relevant to the question. Am I approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: I mean you don't need to make a copy of the original xlsx file. Open it, modify it then save with a new name. You then have two files, the original and the modified.

Comment: I see.. Correct me if I am wrong here. In this instance I did need to make a copy of it because it is protected from editing by the author. Can I have you help me troubleshoot another piece of code within the same file? I can start a new question.

Comment: Protected how? Protections on the sheet may prevent you from modifying cells however Openpyxl can remove the protection to allow that. Again if the file is saved as another name, or basically doesn't overwrite the original file then the original file is never affected. It's faster to disable the protection on the sheet than make a cell by cell copy. Of course if passwords are used and they are unknown then yes you may have no choice.

Comment: It is protected from editing behind a password that I don't have access to. I added another question above. Would love your feedback on why it is not outputting anything.

Comment: (For your first code example):- With the section where you look for the text 'Location..." in order to determine the deletion point. The loop uses max column (mc1) as its range size which means that the cells you are searching only cover this range which is 5 i.e. the cells you are searching are A1-A5, B1-B5, C1-C5 etc. Therfore you will never find that text in cell A10.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your first code example.

Given that you require to copy data from workbook1 to workbook2 due to sheet protection, it makes sense to copy only what you need, rather than copying all then deleting what you don't want.

With this in mind looking at the code example below.

First we check for the location of the start of the text you want to keep which appears to be the string `"Location : 001 General Notes"` and then only copy the data from this row onwards.

The code example searches column A only for the search text. The line

```
ws1.iter_rows(max_col=1)
```

will loop through column A only. When the text is found the code breaks out of that loop and starts another loop from that row, this time across all used columns.

```
for row in ws1.iter_rows(min_row=copy_start_row):
```

`copy_start_row` is the row the search text is found. The cell value at the ws1 current coordinate is copied to the first row same column of ws2 and so on to the end of the used data.

The result is a copy of your existing sheet with the data on ws1 starting at row 10 starting at row 1 on ws2.

```
import openpyxl as xl

# Creates new workbook, saves it over the original, removes design
path1 = "/home/sean-desmet/Delavue/84-22-1037 Piedmont Model Takeoff.xlsx"

wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename=path1)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]

wb2 = xl.Workbook()
ws2 = wb2.active
ws2.title = ws1.title

search_text = "Location : 001 General Notes"

copy_start_row = 1  # Variable for the first row to copy data from
for row in ws1.iter_rows(max_col=1):
    c_val = row[0].value
    if c_val is not None and c_val in search_text:
        print(f'Cell with the value is {row[0].coordinate}')
        copy_start_row = row[0].row
        break  # break from loop when search text found

row_offset = copy_start_row-1  # row offset for location of data in ws2
for row in ws1.iter_rows(min_row=copy_start_row):
    for cell in row:
        ws2.cell(row=cell.row-row_offset,column=cell.column).value = ws1[cell.coordinate].value

wb2.save(path1)  # Possibly want to use a different file name
```